# Tensorflow classification not running correctly with multiprocessing, but is with multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, parallel-processing, tensorflow

I have an app that should be classifying images in parallel every 5 seconds. I want to get around the Global Interpreter Lock, so I am trying to use the multiprocessing library rather than multithreading. More or less, my code looks like this:

```
# Loads label file, strips off carriage return
label_lines = [line.rstrip() for line 
                   in tf.gfile.GFile("/home/aneksteind/tensorflowSource/output_labels.txt")]

# Unpersists graph from file
f = tf.gfile.FastGFile("/home/aneksteind/tensorflowSource/output_graph.pb", 'rb')
graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
_ = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')

sess = tf.Session()
mainGraph = sess.graph

# a function that starts a thread for each region of interest to classify
def checkFrames():
    timer = threading.Timer(5.0, checkFrames)
    timer.daemon = True
    timer.start()
    if(started):
        index = 0
        threads = []
        for roi in rois:
            p = Process(target=containsPlane, args=(frame, roi, index))
            p.daemon = True
            p.start()
            index += 1

def containsPlane(frame, roi, index):
    tempGraph = mainGraph
    tempSession = tf.Session(graph=tempGraph)
    tempTensor = tempSession.graph.get_tensor_by_name('final_result:0')
    predictions = tempSession.run(tempTensor, \
             {'DecodeJpeg:0': subframe})

    ...
```

When I am running this code using a Thread, it runs just fine. It prints out each preliminary message/warnings before classifying for the first time only once and classifies each image, but not in parallel.

When I change to a Process, the preliminary messages/warnings repeatedly show up and the images are never classified. Could this be due to the sessions sharing a state of some sort?  What can I do differently so that multiple images are classified in parallel?

Comment: You can't use `global` vars with `processes`. Vars have to be inside the `process` or you have to use `shared memory`.

Comment: @stovfl how could I tell which variable is the one that needs to be a multiprocess.Value?

Comment: Because TensorFlow uses pthreads internally I don't think it's going to be compatible with the python processing package (the behavior of threaded code in the presence of forks is hard to debug and understand).

Comment: @AlexandrePassos is there a way using tensorflow to run the jobs in parallel (each job has to run the session)?

Comment: If you start many python processes and connect them to the same device using the same cluster spec they will share state. Otherwise you can use C++ threads to call session.run.

Answer (score 0):

> **From TensorFlow doc**: Creates a new TensorFlow session.
>   If no graph argument is specified when constructing the session, the default graph will be launched in the session. If you are using more than one graph (created with tf.Graph() in the same process, you will have to use different sessions for each graph, but each graph can be used in multiple sessions. In this case, it is often clearer to pass the graph to be launched explicitly to the session constructor.

I think you should give `graph=tf.Graph()` as a `parameter` to `def containsPlane(...)`. Try to become independent from `global vars` and try to create the `session` inside `def containsPlane(...)`.

---

You have three arguments `args=(frame, roi, index)`, but I did not see any using of them in `def containsPlane(..)`?

---

> **Question**: ... running this code using a Thread, it runs just fine. ..., but not in parallel.
>   `for roi in rois:
>      threads.append(threading.Thread(...`

You start `roi` `Threads`, so I can't imagin why executing is **not in parallel**?

Your attemp to use `multiprocessing` this way will fail as you should **not** start **more** `processes` as your machine has cores.
Starting more will result in swaping and therefore reduce the overall performance.

> **Question**: how could I tell which variable is the one that needs to be a multiprocess.Value?

All **not** readonly

---

Didn't understand why you doing the following:

```
sess = tf.Session()
mainGraph = sess.graph
# ...
def containsPlane(frame, roi, index):
    tempGraph = mainGraph
    tempSession = tf.Session(graph=tempGraph)
```

Why not simple:

```
def containsPlane(frame, roi, index):
    tempSession = tf.Session()
```

Comment: the threads dont run in parallel already because of the global interpreter lock. as for the other questions, i didnt have the simple example you provided because when I tried that the tensorflow graph could not be found, and I didn't want to load it for each roi (region of interest) that I wanted to classify. the frame is the current frame I am taking a region of interest from

Comment: @DavidAnekstein: Updated my Answer